# How to upload an image using synchronous method in android

Tags: android, android-layout, retrofit

I want to upload an image in android using retrofit synchronous method. I did this with volley Asynchronous like below but now I want to do this with synchronous.

```
private void uploadImage(final String image_path) {
    stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    //Disimissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();
                    //Showing toast message of the response
                    Toast.makeText(ImageUploadActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(ImageUploadActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    //Showing toast
                    Toast.makeText(ImageUploadActivity.this, volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Dismissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            String img_path = image_path;
            //Creating parameters
            Map<String, String> parameters = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            //Adding parameters
            parameters.put("postedFile", img_path);
            parameters.put("folderName", estimateNumber.getText().toString());
            parameters.put("catName", EstimateID.getText().toString());
            parameters.put("estNumber", estimateNumber.getText().toString());
            parameters.put("userName", uploadDestination.getText().toString().concat("/Images"));
            parameters.put("imageUploadID", "2017-10-09 01.43.36 PM");
            parameters.put("dateTime", "2017-10-09 01.43 PM");
            parameters.put("type", "image");
            parameters.put("accessToken", "fgd3Rh@lcr");
            parameters.put("fileName", estNumber.getText().toString().concat(fileNameList.get(j)));
            j++;
            //returning parameters
            return parameters;
        }
    };
    //Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Someone has any idea of how to do it with retrofit or with some other library?

Answer (score 0):

```
interface ImageService {
    @POST Call<String> upload(@Url HttpUrl url, @QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
}

private ImageService getImageService() {

    Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20));
    dispatcher.setMaxRequests(20);
    dispatcher.setMaxRequestsPerHost(1);

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .dispatcher(dispatcher)
            .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
            .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(100, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(HttpUrl.parse("https://example.com/"))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

    return retrofit.create(ImageService.class);
}

private void uploadImage(final String image_path) {

    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameters.put("postedFile", img_path);
    parameters.put("folderName", estimateNumber.getText().toString());
    parameters.put("catName", EstimateID.getText().toString());
    parameters.put("estNumber", estimateNumber.getText().toString());
    parameters.put("userName", uploadDestination.getText().toString().concat("/Images"));
    parameters.put("imageUploadID", "2017-10-09 01.43.36 PM");
    parameters.put("dateTime", "2017-10-09 01.43 PM");
    parameters.put("type", "image");
    parameters.put("accessToken", "fgd3Rh@lcr");
    parameters.put("fileName", estNumber.getText().toString().concat(fileNameList.get(j)));

    getImageService().upload(HttpUrl.parse(UPLOAD_URL), parameters).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            //Disimissing the progress dialog
            loading.dismiss();
            //Showing toast message of the response
            Toast.makeText(ImageUploadActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(ImageUploadActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            //Showing toast
            Toast.makeText(ImageUploadActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Dismissing the progress dialog
            loading.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have to upload the image by hitting url as well by passing some other parameter. The purpose of synchronous is that I want to showing the image counter on the progress bar like if there are 10 images to upload it should shown first 0/10 , 1/10, 2/10....10/10. Is it possible with this ?

Comment: Not sure where you're interacting with the image counter looking at the above code.... but if you want to execute the call synchronously then with Retrofit you would have to use the Call interface which will give you a response or an error - remember though this would need to be done off the main thread. https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html

Also, isn't your code above working asynchronously?

Comment: it is working but I am not able to show here image counter. The progress bar I called in seprate method. Any Idea how I can do this                                                    private void progressDialog(int ab1) {
        this.ab = ab1;
        loading.setMessage("Uploading in progress please wait... ");
        loading.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        //loading.setMax(count);
        //loading.setProgressPercentFormat(null);
        //loading.setProgress(0);
        //loading.setIndeterminate(true);
        loading.show();
    }

Comment: Is it possible with volley to show the image uploading counter for 10 images like when  no image uploaded it should show 0/10 , on first image upload it show 1/10, on second upload it should show 2/10....10/10?

Comment: Its hard to really say without seeing what you're trying to do... nevertheless have updated the answer to show you how the Volley code would translate to Retrofit which is all I can do.